# Getting user in a app.view() handle method

Tags: python, slack-api, trello

I've have a modal for submitting ticket to trello, everything is working great but i need to output in slack a message to the user that his ticket is published.

In the slack api documentation (chapter 'Listening for view submissions') i can read :

```py
# Handle a view_submission request
@app.view("view_1")
def handle_submission(ack, body, client, view, logger):
    user = body["user"]["id"]
```

When i try the same I've got a KeyError: 'user'. Without that line the code work great but I need the user to know that his ticket is published on Trello and provide him the link (and other informations)

EDIT : I've printed the body dict content and nothing about the user :

```py
{
   "id":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "team_id":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "type":"modal",
   "private_metadata":"",
   "callback_id":"ticket_submission",
   "state":{
      "values":{
         "block_type":{
            "type":{
               "type":"static_select",
               "selected_option":{
                  "text":{
                     "type":"plain_text",
                     "text":"Feature",
                     "emoji":true
                  },
                  "value":"feature"
               }
            }
         },
         "block_priority":{
            "priority":{
               "type":"static_select",
               "selected_option":{
                  "text":{
                     "type":"plain_text",
                     "text":"Critical",
                     "emoji":true
                  },
                  "value":"critical"
               }
            }
         },
         "block_description":{
            "description":{
               "type":"plain_text_input",
               "value":"This is the description"
            }
         },
      }
   },
   "hash":"1674058454.YvY8jNKh",
   "title":{
      "type":"plain_text",
      "text":"Create Ticket",
      "emoji":true
   },
   "clear_on_close":false,
   "notify_on_close":false,
   "close":{
      "type":"plain_text",
      "text":"Cancel",
      "emoji":true
   },
   "submit":{
      "type":"plain_text",
      "text":"Submit",
      "emoji":true
   },
   "previous_view_id":"None",
   "root_view_id":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "app_id":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "external_id":"",
   "app_installed_team_id":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "bot_id":"XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: Well, `print(body)` before that line, and look what the value is

Comment: Added the print of the body

Comment: I don't know what the body is supposed to look like, so what exactly is your question? The error is saying `body["user"]` doesn't exist, as you can see. So, you can check `if "user" not in body`, and ignore the event, or throw your own error...

Comment: According to documentation : https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#view_submissions the user can be retreived this way : `body["user"]["id"]`  . I don't want to throw an error, i need the user so my question is how to get the user (or user id) since my modal doesn't give me the user in the resulting dict

Comment: I suggest filing a bug ticket with Slack, then https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/issues. Or, you are simply getting some view events that don't have a user, and you can conditionally ignore them